# Inject mock to an InterceptorHandler

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, springmockito

I'm trying to inject a mock in an InterceptorHandler but I've could configure it.

I have an Interceptor like this:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        // ... 
        service.findOne(...);
    }

}
```

and my test look like this:

```
protected MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
protected Service service;

...

when(service.findOne(anyString()))
    .thenReturn(null);
mockMvc.perform(put("somepath")
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The interceptor works fine but when I'm debugging, I see that service is null, in the interceptor, so I want to know if is there a way to mock service?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are you annotating your test class? You might need to annotate your test class as manageable object so that is can construct the mocked service

Comment: These are the annotations that I use in the test class. @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers={...})